# Converting Model to list in an MVC test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, visual-studio-2012, casting

I'm running tests using NSubstitute in VS2012 and I'm trying to convert a Model to a list, or something I can count. Here's the code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void StartedGame()
    {
        // arrange
        var repo = Substitute.For<IGameRepository>();
        IEnumerable<Game> expectedGames = new List<Game> 
            {
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 1, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 2, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 2, hasStarted = false, ID = 3, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 2, hasStarted = false, ID = 4, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 5, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false}
            };
        repo.GetGames().Returns(expectedGames);
        var sut = new GameController(repo);

        // act
        var actual = sut.GameMenuStart();
        // assert
        //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(ViewResult));
        var viewResult = actual as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
    }
```

When I debug, I can hover over 'viewResult' and see Model and there I see the entries and the 'count', but how can I reach it? I've tried casting to 'Game' object like so:

```
Game[] theModel = (Game[])viewResult.Model;
```

And to list and more, but it always fails.
Any ideas?

EDIT: viewResult is of type: System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult

Here is the rest of the code inside this function:

```
        var repo = Substitute.For<IGameRepository>();
        IEnumerable<Game> expectedGames = new List<Game> 
            {
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 1, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 2, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 2, hasStarted = false, ID = 3, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 2, hasStarted = false, ID = 4, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false},
                new Game{ gameTypeID = 1, hasStarted = false, ID = 5, isOver = false, isPublic = true, maxPlayers = 2, someoneReported = false}
            };
        repo.GetGames().Returns(expectedGames);
        var sut = new GameController(repo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var theList = viewResult.Model as IEnumerable<Game>;`

This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an IEnumerable you can just use the "ToArray" method if you want it to be an array.

```
Game[] theModel = viewResult.ToArray();
```

However the `.Count` should just work?

can we see the signature of "`repo.GetGames()`"

Comment: I've added more to it, along with the type of viewResult. It does not contain the 'ToArray()' extension.